# How to keep decimal precision in multiplication and division(in jQuery, javascript)?

Tags: jquery, precision

I have the following function which can do multiplication and division for some business logic in jQuery

```
var rate = 39.5;
var IndiviualPercentageTaxes = 20;
var TotalPercentageTaxes = 20;

var r1 = rate* 100 / (100 + IndiviualPercentageTaxes);  

var r2 = r1* (100 + TotalPercentageTaxes)/100;

var finalRate = Math.round(r2));
```

The finalRate is **39**, but the expected result is **40**.....

I can easily rewrite the program to avoid losing decimal precision in calculation, like the following:

```
  var r2 = rate*(100 + TotalPercentageTaxes)/(100 +TotalPercentageTaxes)
```

However, this will skip r1, and I need r1 for other purpose in the whole program.

This also caused a confusion that no one knows what this formula really means since I combine two calculations into one.

Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you going to be doing a lot of this sort of thing?  If not, then just use the correct calculation and leave a comment to the future reader telling them why it is being done that way.

But if you are doing lot, you need real precision numbers.  There are a few libraries out there. This one: [https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/)/   is probably the best fit for you.

"Big Numbers" is a term from Common Lisp and Java and it captures the idea of both very large numbers and very *long* numbers (for precision), and oftentimes keeping numbers in their "big" format (ie, as unsolved expressions), until needed.